# My wordpress updated automatically

Tags: wordpress, azure

Without changing anything WordPress version updated from 4.9.4 to 4.9.5. on Azure server.

[image: wordpress_version]

Please let me know how this happened?

Comment: Why do you ask here instead of Azure support?

Comment: @Filburt - this is unrelated to Azure support. It's specific to WordPress configuration.

Comment: I'd suggest posting this on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) if you're having configuration issues related to auto-updates. Unfortunately off-topic here, as it's not related to programming. That said: This seems like a core configuration issue. Not sure this would be topical on the WordPress site...

Answer (score -1):

It is an auto-update. (as already show in the image you posted)

By default, only minor releases – such as for maintenance and security purposes are auto-updated but they are configurable. This is the recommended behavior.

However this can be prevented by defining certain constants or by applying filter hooks

#### To completely disable all types of automatic updates, core or otherwise, add the following to your wp-config.php file:

`define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );`

### You can also disable all automatic updates using the following filter:

`add_filter( 'automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_true' );`

It is also possible to allow the partial updates.
The detailed instruction can be found in the link https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-automatic-background-updates/